# Why I can't convert my variables to float in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics

Greeting,
I have a simple question. I have a data set and that is my data set e.g.[image]

And this is my code:

```
veri<-read.table("veri.txt",header=T,sep=" ",dec=",") 
veri$y = formatC(veri$y, digits = 8, format = "f")
veri$x1 <- as.integer(veri$x1)
veri
summary(veri)

describe(veri)
```

And I get this results:
[image: results]

Why I cant convert my variables types factor to numeric? This codes giving me false result I dont know what is this result about of what. How can I convert my variables with 14 decimal numbers?
EDIT: Thats my data set link: `https://e.edim.co/68132793/qUVd3DjpoYI5y9ll.txt?response-content-disposition=filename%3D"file_32_21621672__Oguz_Bozkurt.txt"%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27file%252032_21621672%2520%2520Oguz%2520Bozkurt.txt&Expires=1588445799&Signature=hrvAUnEmmjVTB7E0EcVhuP4Fa~RhxbMZNeNn7uiBzzzp2vhrJonir8xW1WDtM7NQc1FTRuZE0Vxig5ChVHmpxuywHrZ~~KWUAqxJhH2dC43HQMr9SHQW4h~cyXOP1QEFFKzlCYoyI~5zMd8TyRIRuxDqEQIQM~zUslyDfqHd~Un24jWTvj42bPhdfjSKaKfJmYvpbzhWFjKDJPdPKqJ3C2If6g0Mqzk0My0kPDl97VgvsOr8O7g46BRJ0aW6mlqQ9VhKLKZ6TCmi-4ZAyXuQNVdPcCEMh65sgfJ8dPJ2vy6E2A2gQrk0z3TeAyh3DDlnz4cZB4DDFLRq5ekkK8Gpcg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJMSU6JYPN6FG5PBQ`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: If a column is a `factor`, then try `as.integer(as.character(veri$x1))`. Otherwise you're just converting the `factor` integers (internal references to unique strings), which is rarely what is intended with this kind of code. (Is there a reason you're truncating all floats to integers?)

Comment: integers is not usefull for me. I need decimals sensei

Comment: If you need decimals, then why are you using `as.integer`? Links to data are discouraged, for several reasons: (1) unfamiliar links could be scams/phishing, etc, so many users are hesitant to click on them; (2) even if familiar and trustworthy-looking, it's an extra step that often give quick answerers a reason to skip your question; (3) when the link goes stale, the question returns to *"not reproducible"* and to a lower level of usefulness and quality. Please make the question self-contained and reproducible.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(veri$x1))` - general principle as @r2evans mentioned is you need to coerce to strings first, then do any subsequent conversions. If you upgrade to R 4.0.0, then `read.table` should actually bring the column in as numeric or string instead of factor